# iOS Swift 4 images from html string not loading in WK WebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode, webview

I'm having problems with loading images from a html string in a WKWebView. Doens't work in UIWebView either.

The html string comes from an API and I have to display the content as is, I don't have control over the tags or content.
The image is embedded like in the example below.

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" title="" class="colorbox" data-colorbox-gallery="gallery-paragraphs_item-7725-ZrzXIAds_FA" data-cbox-img-attrs=" &quot;&quot;}"></a>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```

I tried changing info.plist to enable App Transport Security Settings, no change.
All the examples out there are with  tags in the html text, but as you can see here, I have to display them from link tags.

Comment: `<a href="someImage.jpg" />` is a link to an image... not an image? i would expect to see `<img src="someImage.jpg" />`. Is there a JavaScript library that is loading these urls and maybe transforming them into a carousel or something similar?. Use the simulator to run the app and then use your mac's Safari develop menu to inspect the webview and see if there are any JS errors being thrown

Answer (score 0):

add `<Img>` tag inside of `<a>`, like this,

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" title="" class="colorbox" data-colorbox-gallery="gallery-paragraphs_item-7725-ZrzXIAds_FA" data-cbox-img-attrs=" &quot;&quot;}"><img alt="ImageName" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg"></a>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is another paragraph</p>
```